# Trying to get property of non-object - retrieve set of data in laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having this issue with laravel when I'm getting data from two tables.This is my query. It exists in a controller.

```
$switches = DB::table('sw_pairs')->
   join('cust_sw_pair','cust_sw_pair.sw_pair_id', '=', 'sw_pairs.sw_pair_id')->
   select(
        DB::raw(
                'cust_sw_pair.sw_pair_id,  
                 count(cust_sw_pair.sw_pair_id) as totcount, 
                 pri_sw, sec_sw, 
                 count(if(pri_sw_admin_status="Admin Down" AND sec_sw_admin_status="Admin Down", 1, NULL)) as downCount')
         )->
   groupBy('cust_sw_pair.sw_pair_id')->get();
```

When I execute this query I get this error.

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

but the above query is succesfully returning the first row of the result set when I used `first()` instead of the `get()` method.

This is the retrieving part which  exists on the view:

```
@foreach($switches as $switch_pair)  
   <tr>  
   <td>{{$switches->pri_sw}} / {{$switches->sec_sw}}</td>  
   <td><span>{{$switches->downCount}},{{$switches->totcount}</span></td>  
   <td><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> 40% </td>  
   <td>{{$switches->downCount}} / {{$switches->totcount}}</td></tr>  
@endforeach
```

How can I successfully get all the results?

Comment: `$switches` should be `$switch_pair` inside the foreach

Comment: Seem to be missing a bunch of `>` : `DB::table('sw_pairs')->join(...)->select(DB::raw(...))->groupBy('cust_sw_pair.sw_pair_id')->get();`

Comment: read about loops in Blade: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures

Comment: its not about blade templating and view. i just want to get all the data by using get() method in controller. first method gives one raw. but after using get method, it generates that error. #steve

Comment: i'm assigning resukt set into the variable called $switches and passing it into my controller. I definetly sure there is no issue. #moppo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- a) you are looping through `$switches` but are not using the single items within the loops
- b) missing accolade in the second td

So to give you the result of the above fixed:

```
@foreach($switches as $switch_pair)  
   <tr>  
   <td>{{ $switch_pair->pri_sw }} / {{ $switch_pair->sec_sw }}</td>  
   <td><span>{{ $switch_pair->downCount }},{{ $switch_pair->totcount }}</span></td>  
   <td><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> 40% </td>  
   <td>{{ $switch_pair->downCount }} / {{ $switch_pair->totcount }}</td></tr>  
@endforeach
```

Comment: then this error is generating.    _Cannot use object of type stdClass as array_  @Luceos

Comment: wow man that worked. Thanks mate. If u visit srilanka i promise to give you a free wildlife journey ride :D